# Why have different ways of variable initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, initialization

Since the 2011 revision of C++ standards, variables can be initialized in three different ways given below.

```
int i = 0;
int i (0);
int i {0};
```

As far as I know all three different initializations have the same effect. If they all have the same effect, why not stick to one way of initialisation like the first one? Is there any special need to initialise variables by surrounding their initial values in () or {}?

Comment: For primitive types it's mostly the same. There are differences in implicit casting. But for other types there are big difference. There is a difference between `std::vector<int> i(0)` and `std::vector<int> i{0}` and `std::vector<int> i = 0` gives an error.

Comment: there are much more than 3 ways, but there is not a single reason to have more than one

Comment: Copy initialization, direct initialization and list initialization do not always give the same result.

Comment: [Initialization in C++ is bonkers](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/initialization-is-bonkers/)

Comment: *"Is there any special need to initialise variables by surrounding their initial values in () or {}?"* Yes.

Comment: Braced initialization can be used to initialize non-static data member, prohibit implicit narrowing conversion,  easy to avoid vexing parse.

Comment: Try it with `int i = Bar()`,  `int i(Bar())`, and `int i{Bar()}` and you'll find one of them is different - if you subsequently try to use `i`.

Comment: It's history. I sometimes wonder what it would be like to rationalize all the redundancies out of `C++` with no thought to backward compatibility and reproduce `C++` anew from the ground up.

Comment: 3 way?  There are dozens.  q.v. [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.

Comment: @Eljay whaaaat? Holy moly!

Answer (score 3):

The reason for not disallowing any of the three is to maintain backward compatibility.

There are tons of code, in production, that is written with each of the three ways. If the standards were to be changed, working code would need to be rewritten, causing costs and possibly bugs. Since the C++ committee is very serious about backward compatibility, we end up in this situation. It is still way better than other language like Python, where, from minor version to minor version, you need to rewrite code to format a string, or to loop from zero to ten.

If you have the choice, pick `{0}`, it's called uniform initialization for a reason :-)

Answer (score 3):

It is an historical question. The first one is `int i=0;`. This one is from the early C language from the 1970's. Next first C++ versions introduced a function like initialization syntax which writes here `int i(0);`. But because of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) ambiguities, the curly braces initialization was invented.

And for compatibility reasons, all those syntaxes are still valid...

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
int i (0); //For backward compatibility
int i {0}; //Uniform Initialization
```

There is a difference in these 3 types of initializations.

```
int i = 2.2;
int i (2.2);
int i {2.2};
```

First, two will do the implicit conversion but `int i {0};` will give you error/warning for parameter narrowing.

For details about initializer list [check this](https://youtu.be/XjkRIc5mDK8) video.

Comment: Please mark as an answer, if this is what expected.

Comment: `int i {0};` on its own has nothing to do with an initializer list. Also "Mark it as answer if this" has nothing to do with the answer and shouldn't be included. Other than that, nice point about conversion!

Comment: Thanks @George for suggestions. Regarding {}, it's a new generalized way of initialization. It is recommended to use always but be careful, it has side effects in some special cases.  Maybe you are comparing it will std::initializer_list. These two are different. But there is a very interesting relation between these. I explained it in the video, I linked.

Comment: I was referring to `int i {0}; //Initializer list way`, it should probably be `int i {0}; // Uniform initialization`. I know the language is confusing but initializer lists are something different which themselves are different from list initialization. See [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), initialization in c++ is just crazy.